# awscli query not working with no Tags and no Name - multi tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I am trying to use aws cli command to filter based on volumetype and status with no name tag and additional tag something like below

```
 aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=volume-type,Values=gp2 Name=status,Values="available" --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `Name`].Value,Tags[?Key == `Alias`].Value)]'
```

The above cli works but the notnull part is not applying to both the tags. Its only filtering volumes which doesnt have Tag as "Name" but it is still listing all the volumes which have the tag as "Alias"

I would like both of them(tagged as Name and Alias) NOT come up - basically

Well, based on this [link](https://blog.corpinfo.com/using-aws-cli-to-find-untagged-instances) : which is only filtering one tag

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filters Name=volume-type,Values=gp2 Name=status,Values="available" --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `Name`]'
```

EDIT: trying to do something similar to describe snapshots with StartTime

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids "***********"  --query 'Snapshots[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `Name`]) && !not_null(Tags[?Key == `Alias`])  && ?StartTime>=`2017-09-15`]'
```

Getting a error...Is it possible to provide a date range above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JMESPath `and` expression](http://jmespath.org/proposals/improved-filters.html#and-expressions) so writing something similar as

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes \
--filters Name=volume-type,Values=gp2 Name=status,Values="available" \
--query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `Name`]) && !not_null(Tags[?Key == `Alias`])]'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Your answer worked like a charm. I updated the question for describe-snapshots. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Its good but you dont need the `?` before StartTime as you already have the marker at the beginning, just add `&& StartTime >= ``2017-09-15``]` and it should work